# "This file cannot be previewed because the following previewer has been disabled: Microsoft PowerPoint previewer."

Tags: microsoft-outlook, attachments, preview

[image: Message Screenshot]

After clicking on the attachment, and before the message shown above appears, the following transient message is seen for a few moments:

> "Starting Microsoft PowerPoint previewer..."

Clicking on the <kbd>Enable previewer</kbd> button (also shown in the screenshot above) does nothing.

**Steps/fixes already attempted**:

1. I have gone through the first three fixes described on the following webpage but the previewer is still disabled:
   https://www.technipages.com/outlook-fix-this-file-cannot-be-previewed.
2. I deleted the files from the temporary Outlook folder.
3. I recently upgraded from Office 365 personal to Business. Although I deleted the personal Office installation, and "repaired" the business installation, the issue persists.
4. Completed the steps suggested by @Perry's answer below.

**Updates:**
Once in a while (every few weeks) the issue spontaneously resolves and I’m able to preview the PowerPoint file but the issue inevitably returns.

Comment: Is it unique to this powerpoint file? (what happens if you e-mail yourself a blank powerpoint?)

Comment: @T-Rez It is not unique to this PowerPoint file. I tried previewing several other PPT files and get the same message.

Answer (score 1):

Can you double click to open the .ppt file?

Can you preview other attachment? Such as Word or Excel file?

If issue could occur if the ‘TEMP’ folder is full. When you open an attachment in your email, a copy of this attachment will be saved in the temp folder automatically. We can delete files in that folder. Please refer to the steps in [this article](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2269-outlook-open-temp-folder.html) to open this folder

We can also try running a repair of your Office installation to see the result. To do this, please go to Control Panel > Programs and Features. Right click your Office suit and then choose Change. Click Repair.

Besides, please set PowerPoint as the default application to open .pptx file

Comment: Yes, I can double click to open the .ppt file. Yes, I can preview at least Excel and .pdf files. I opened the Outlook temp folder and deleted the files therein and also reapired my office installation, but the issue persists.

Comment: We can try opening Outlook in safe mode to see if the issue continues. Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /safe and then press Enter. This helps eliminate whether the problem lies on any third party add-ins.

Comment: I found one link here, please check if the registry for PowerPoint was set correctly: https://superuser.com/questions/1094154/outlook-2013-cant-preview-office-files

Comment: I opened Outlook in safe mode and the problem persisted.

Comment: I also took the steps outlined in the first answer posted to https://superuser.com/questions/1094154/outlook-2013-cant-preview-office-files. However, the issues persists.

Comment: We could use Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant (SaRA) to run tests to resolve many different problems. It can gather the Outlook profile configuration information that's helpful when you troubleshoot problems. For more details, please refer to this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4098558/how-to-scan-outlook-by-using-the-sara-tool

Comment: I ran the SaRA and it detected seven issues: 1) No MX record for 'rwjbh.org" found running 'Nslookup.exe -type=mx -timeout=15 rwjbh.org'; 2) Delay sending email because Deferred sending rule is configured; 3 - 6) The problamatic add-in ['EnterpriseVault.DesktopUI' x2, 'Phishline' x2] was re-enabled by you; 7) The file Msoutl.olb is not registered properly.